# How to integrate Paynimo payment gateway in Angular 5 app?

Tags: angular, payment-gateway

I am developing an web application which has the payment integration and the client has chosen the [Paynimo](https://www.paynimo.com/paynimo/index.html) payment gateway.

They have documentation for javascript, that can be seen [here](https://www.tecprocesssolution.com/proto/p2m/client/salt-based-documentation.htm#online)

I have no idea how to implement this in my Angular 5 App.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be one `index.html` file in your angular app. If the jquery is not included through `angular.config.json` include the jquery then in the index.html file

either of this

```
UAT Checkout JS Link
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.tecprocesssolution.com/proto/P2M/server/lib/checkout.js"></script>

Live Checkout JS Link
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.paynimo.com/Paynimocheckout/server/lib/checkout.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JohnConde I just want to know why it's considered as off-topic question? At least it would help me for further questions!

Comment: @brk Thanx.. I tried that. But couldn't get the response inside handle response function which is also included in index.html file!

Comment: @JohnConde I feel the user is struggling with adding an external library , to angular 5 project, this is mainly because we are accustomed to do npm install libraries and may users may not be aware that external libraries can be added directly to `index.html` project. I will be happy if my answer help him

Comment: @KarthikArwin from the page `$.pnCheckout(configJson);` is called on a button click and `configJson` is a the object which is passed to it & its description is given to same page. in angular 5 application create a button and add a function to it. Inside this function call `$.pnCheckout(configJson)` . You can create a separate function in angular component file instead of `handleResponse`

Comment: go through the document of the gateway hopefully you will able to understand